# Flask - db 'unique' constraint works, but not returning error so that I can flash message to user if username/email taken. How to inform the user?

Tags: python, postgresql, flask, error-handling, unique-constraint

Usernames and emails must be unique in my Flask database User model, which uses PostgreSQL. This is the view/route for my website's registration page:

```
@auth.route('/register', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
    reg_form = RegistrationForm()

    if reg_form.validate_on_submit():
        try:
            user = User(username=reg_form.username.data, password=reg_form.password.data,
                        email=reg_form.email.data)
            db.session.add(user)
            db.session.commit()

            send_email("Welcome!", "email/welcome_msg",
                        user.email, user=user)

            return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))
        except:
            flash("Test")

    title = _("Register")
    return render_template("auth/register.html",
                           reg_form=reg_form,
                           title=title)
```

When you enter an existing username or email into the registration form, the `unique` constraint in my database model works as no new data is added to the database is created and the website remains on the registration page rather than redirecting to the login page.

However, it is apparent that no `IntegrityError` or any other such error is returned when someone tries to register a username or email address which is already taken, so the `except` portion where a message is supposed to flash does not occur, regardless of whether or not the `except` is specific or not.

In my efforts to provide an error message in the event that someone attempts to register with an existing username or email, I have also tried checking the database for an existing username like so:

```
def register():
    reg_form = RegistrationForm()

    if reg_form.validate_on_submit():
            user = User(username=reg_form.username.data, password=reg_form.password.data,
                        email=reg_form.email.data)

            if db.session.query(db.exists().where(User.username == reg_form.username.data)).scalar():
                flash("Test")
            else:
                db.session.add(user)
                db.session.commit()

                send_email("Welcome!", "email/welcome_msg",
                           user.email, user=user)

            return redirect(url_for("auth.login"))

    title = _("Register")
    return render_template("auth/register.html",
                           reg_form=reg_form,
                           title=title)
```

However, this doesn't seem to work either as no message gets flashed. I have tried a few variations of the above, but have not had any success yet. I will note that I am using Flask-Toastr to flash the messages, but I don't think that is very relevant as it has worked fine with a number of other 'if-else' and 'try-except' statements I have used.

Answer (score 0):

you also need to place the flash message in your html template file:

```
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() %}
        {% if messages %}
        <ul>
            {% for message in messages %}
            <li>{{ message }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
        {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
```

Comment: That's definitely not it. I am using Flask-Toastr (https://pypi.org/project/Flask-Toastr/) and don't have any such `with messages` section in my code and yet the flashed messages appear in a number of other cases. It is only this one page where they aren't working. I am sure the issue must lie with the database somehow.

Comment: i see, i'm not familiar with flask-toastr.